# High lyphocytes count in blood test

Tags: blood, blood-tests, hematology

What is the lymphocytes counts limit which discriminates a recent infection from a CLL (Chronical Leukaemia Lymphocytosis)?

Comment: Normal Lymphocytes counts is from 1,000 to 5,000 per ml.  A count of 12,000 Lymphocytes per ml can be caused by a recent infection? Or is it almost surely due to CLL?

Comment: Welcome to MedicalSciences.SE! Please take the [tour] and read the [help]. For [reasons mentioned in this post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411) and in [ask], we require prior research information when asking questions. *See [this list of helpful resources](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/a/784)*. Please help us to help you and [edit] your question to provide more information on what you have read on this subject, what made you ask this question, and any problems you are having understanding your research. If you found nothing, what did you Google?